# Why RelativeLayout does not fill entire height

Tags: android-layout

How to fill entire height by elements inside of RelativeLayout automatically.
I'd like to add a few TextViews.
So how to exclude  empty space on the bottom?

The performance now is as follows:

[image]

If I replace layout_height to 
    'android:layout_height="fill_parent"'
in all TextViews inside of RelativeLayout,
then first TextView(TITLE) occupies 100% of height.
Other elements are not visible.
As I understand weight does not work for RelativeLayout

My XML is below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:background="#EEEECC"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<View
        android:id="@+id/line0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView0"
        android:background="#aaaaaa" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NAME1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line0"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1R"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="111111"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />

<View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#AAAAAA" />
```

Comment: If you want to use weights, you have to switch to a LinearLayout (orientation="vertical" is optional, since it's the default value). Then set the weights for each TextView and set their heights to 0dp. LinearLayout's weightSum is also optional, since Android calculates it by itself

Comment: RelativeLayout seems more comfortable since I have  two TextView elements in the same row. If no solutions with RelativeLayout, then yes, I will use LinearLayout. But I have to use nested LinearLayouts as the rows with TextViews.

Comment: For the rows, you can use a RelativeLayouts (if you don't need weights).